# How can i disable the div to stop closing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Every 5 seconds I'm fetching data from database for my notification. However, every 5 seconds the notification `div` is closing, and I want the `div` to stay open. How can I achieve this?

**NOTE** The ajax calling,fetching is working. I just want my notification `div` to stop closing when the `setinterval` triggered.

Here's the `div`

[image]

home.php

```
<div id="notificationsss">
          </div>



      $(document).ready(function()

        {

          loadnotif();
          setInterval( loadnotif, 5000 );

          $("#notificationsss").on("click",$("#notificationLink"), function() {
            $("#notificationContainer").fadeToggle(300);
        $("#notification_count").fadeOut("slow");

        });




        });

 function loadnotif(){

              $.ajax({
                url:'getrecords.php',
                method:'POST',
                data:{
                  "loadnotif": 1
                },
                success:function(data){
                  $('#notificationsss').html(data);
                }
              });
            }
```

getrecords.php

```
if(isset($_POST['loadnotif'])){

                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM notification";
                          $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
                          $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);


          $output = '      <ul id="main-menu" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                   <li class="dropdown hidden-xs">
                    <li id="notification_li">
                    <a href="#" id="notificationLink"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i>     
                        <span class="notification-counter" style="background-color:red;border-radius:3px;padding: 1px 3px;position:relative;top:-9px;right:9px;font: 8px Verdana;;">'.$count.'</span></a>

                    <div id="notificationContainer">
                    <div id="notificationTitle" style="text-align:center;background-color:#ba4f46;color:#fff;">Notifications</div>
                    <div id="notificationsBody" class="notifications">';


                       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

           $output .='       <a href="viewlecture.php?subjdescr='.$row['subj_descr'].'" style="display:block;color:black;margin-top:10px;background-color:#f6e9e8;" id="notifa">
                          <div>
                            <img src="img/izuku.jpg" style="max-width:50px;max-height:70px;float:left;margin:0px 10px;">
                             <p style="display:inline;margin-top:20px;"><strong>'.$row['fac_code'] .'</strong> '.$row['notif_description'].'<strong><br> '.ucwords(strtolower($row['subj_descr'])).'</strong></p>
                             <p style="font-size:12px;">'.$row['date'].'</p>
                                <hr>
                          </div>

                        </a>';
                      }


       $output .='           </div>
                   <div id="notificationFooter" style="background-color:#ba4f46;"><a href="#" style="color:#fff;">See All</a></div>
                    </div>
                    </li>
            </li>


          </ul>';

          echo $output;

   }
```

Comment: What element is this: $("#notificationsss")? It's not there.

Comment: Oh. Sorry. It's a div where i put the notification div.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested it & found ok. Have you put your ajax called div inside getrecords.php file ? The process is - it will call that file & collect info from it & replace data inside your preferred div.

page1.php

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function()

    {

      loadnotif();
      setInterval( loadnotif, 5000 );

      $("#notificationsss").on("click",$("#notificationLink"), function() {
        $("#notificationContainer").fadeToggle(300);
    $("#notification_count").fadeOut("slow");

    });




    });

function loadnotif(){

          $.ajax({
            url:'getrecords.php',
            type:'POST',
            data:{
              "loadnotif1": 1
            },
            success:function(data){

              $('#notificationsss').html(data);
            }
          });
        }
```

```
<div id="notificationsss">

</div>
```

getrecords.php should be like this

```
if(isset($_POST['loadnotif'])){

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM notification";
                      $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
                      $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);


      $output = '      <ul id="main-menu" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
               <li class="dropdown hidden-xs">
                <li id="notification_li">
                <a href="#" id="notificationLink"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i>     
                    <span class="notification-counter" style="background-color:red;border-radius:3px;padding: 1px 3px;position:relative;top:-9px;right:9px;font: 8px Verdana;;">'.$count.'</span></a>

                <div id="notificationContainer">
                <div id="notificationTitle" style="text-align:center;background-color:#ba4f46;color:#fff;">Notifications</div>
                <div id="notificationsBody" class="notifications">';


                   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

       $output .='       <a href="viewlecture.php?subjdescr='.$row['subj_descr'].'" style="display:block;color:black;margin-top:10px;background-color:#f6e9e8;" id="notifa">
                      <div>
                        <img src="img/izuku.jpg" style="max-width:50px;max-height:70px;float:left;margin:0px 10px;">
                         <p style="display:inline;margin-top:20px;"><strong>'.$row['fac_code'] .'</strong> '.$row['notif_description'].'<strong><br> '.ucwords(strtolower($row['subj_descr'])).'</strong></p>
                         <p style="font-size:12px;">'.$row['date'].'</p>
                            <hr>
                      </div>

                    </a>';
                  }


   $output .='           </div>
               <div id="notificationFooter" style="background-color:#ba4f46;"><a href="#" style="color:#fff;">See All</a></div>
                </div>
                </li>
        </li>


      </ul>';

      echo $output;

  }
```

Comment: The fetching is working. But my problem is the div is closing automatically every time i fetched the data in 5 seconds.

Comment: where you have put your 
`<div id="notificationsss"></div>` ? put it in first page. I have used two page(suppose page1.php, where I have put my scripts & `<div id="notificationsss"></div>`) and another page named  getrecords.php.

Comment: You don't understand my question sir.

Comment: I think, I have understood your question. The problem, when you fetched data after 5 seconds, this div is closing automatically. For this reason, I have mentioned that you need to keep that div in another page & reload contents from another ajax called page, I have tested it from my side & it's working perfectly. Can you please run it at first?

Comment: It's in different page bro. I have two page the `home.php` where the div ajax script is located. and `getrecords.php` where the queries is located. I give you scenerio, i click the notification it's open but when the 5 seconds already count the div is closing.